# Use static library in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, lib

I am developing a module for Linux kernel. It export some function for my partner call in system call (my partner modified system call source code in Linux kernel).
Can I build static lib for my module a just send lib, header file for my partner?

Comment: Yes you can, why not ?

Comment: You realize that static library is basically just an object file, right? Or you are curious, how to link against static library in kernel Makefile?

Comment: Are you mean I can use a lib like *.o file in Linux kernel?

Comment: It's unclear why you can't send sources to your partner or even why you are not sharing same Git repository.

Comment: @rum No, I mean static library is just an archived object file. And your partner's code certainly could be linked against it at linking stage, this is just a matter of preparing his Makefile properly. But it's not commonly used approach among kernel developers, so I'd not recommend it. **0andriy** told you how it should be done in most proper way: just share your git repo (which contains sources of your module) with your partner. If your module is proprietary and you don't want to share the code with your partner (very bad if so), just send him built `.ko` module.

Comment: I can share code with my partner but I want to encapsulated code as lib and send my partner and them will build custom Linux kernel with my lib. @Sam Protsenko, how to build lib *.ko with Linux kernel when I build custom kernel? Is it add lib and header file in make file?

Comment: @rum Just make your module out-of-tree, then you can share its code (separate from kernel) with your partner. [Here](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch02.pdf) is described how to create out-of-tree module and how to build it.

Comment: It's possible use insmod because we build firmware for embedded devices, we can't change anythings when firmware builded. I want to build module when build firmware. How can I do that?

Comment: I describe more details. My partners modified some system call like kill(), open()... and inside these function they call hook function that I coding to check input, if input match conditions, the hook function will do some actions. I have just dev hook function and I want to build it like a lib and send for my partner header file .h and static lib file (because my company policy, I can't send them the source code). My partner will use this lib and build static when them build the new kernel. What kind of lib I should use? How to build lib with kernel? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we provide those as kernel module itself... not library.... not sure what you mean exactly. you want to run "ar" command and build it as static library format and linking it in compile time?

Never tried but nobody does it in kernel-space though...

If you want, make separate module which is library.

As you know, printk, strcpy, memcpy and all these are available in kernel space but nobody links it as "library format" as far as i understood.

Comment: Kernel cannot load *.a file for static library. Kernel cannot load *.so file. Only way to deliver your library to kernel is *.ko